# Error open an Android app via a URL

Tags: android

I want to open my app from an URL where I can publish on Twitter, Facebook, etc. To do that I have defined an activity what I want to call when I make click over the link called "SetPointsActivity". The link would be something like `http:// goo.gl/oMdIVz`.

I have defined the activity in my AndroidManifest.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.comapk/res/android"
package="demo31.mobiltool" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".OriginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SetPointsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_set_points"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="goo.gl" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I receive the link in a message in my twitter account:

[image]

But, I don't know what I am doing wrong because when I make clic on the link what I get is to open the link on a new tab of the browser and not to open my app.

What am I doing wrong?

---

If in my AndroidManifest.xml I change

```
<data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="goo.gl"/>
```

by

```
<data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="abc.gl"/>
```

or

```
<data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="demo31.com"/>
```

It doesn't work. I don't understand what happened!

---

I have made modifications on my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="demo31.mobiltool" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".OriginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SetPointsOnMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_set_points"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="goo.gl" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When I receive the tweet message and make click over the link received I'm redirected to `http://goo.gl` and not show the Activity what I want to call

[image]

Without closing the browser if I go to the next url `http://goo.gl` I'm redirected to Google Url Shortener again. But if I close my browser and all the tabs and open again writing the url http://goo.gl on the browser again, it works! Android shows me the possibility to go to the activity that I want!

[image]

What happened? Why can't I go to my activity making click over the link? If I access first from the link, why I have to close the browser first and then I can access to my activity?

---

I have been made more tests but with other browser. Previously, I have been made test with Chrome browser and the browser of the emulator. With these browsers I have had too many problems. But the new test made it with Firefox with the same configuration of my AndroidManifest.xml works fine!

For example, with this AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="demo31.mobiltool" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".OriginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SetPointsOnMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_set_points"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

If I write on Firefox the next url my.special.scheme://whatever ... The browser opens directly my app. Why can't I do with Chrome or Emulator Browser the same?